# How to count most visited pages in last: hour / day / week / month / year ? - PHP+MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Easiest way would be just save every visit to new row like;

```
page_visits_table
page_id | timestamp
1         time()
1         time()
2         time()
```

and then create scheduled event for every hour / day / week / month / year
to count rows where "page_id" is same and timestamp is small enough. And then just save rowCount value to somewhere...

But if site has 100 000 visitors every day and one visitor visits average 5 pages =

100 000 * 5 * 356 days = 178 000 000 rows.

...so table-size will grow way too big. There must be some smart way to do this without overloading database..?

Comment: Why not use a analytics reporting tool, like Google Analytics? There is a excellent open source alternative, written in PHP with MySQL as a database, called **Piwik**. Use a solution like these, instead of having to log each page visit.

Comment: Thank you! I was checking that Piwik, but it seems a bit too complicated for my purpose. I try to build a simple PHP-script for showing users a list of most readed articles by day / week / month @ my site.

Comment: I still recommend Piwik. It has a API that you could use to retrieve any information about your visits. I've been using it for a year and a half and it simply rocks, plus you do not have to reinvent the wheel again just to keep track of your visits.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me this direction Vasilis Lourdas! :) I studied this Piwik and I have to say it's very interesting! I understood that it's possible to create "scheduled tasks for executing php-scripts" with Piwik? ...I installed Pikiw to my local xampp-server, but I can't find any options or "panel" for creating events.. I quess scheduled tasks need linux-server? I readed from here: http://piwik.org/blog/2014/08/create-scheduled-task-introducing-piwik-platform/

Answer (score 0):

As other pointed out, using data from third party data collectors should be most efficient for you.

But if you're still interrested in an answer the DIY-way:

The question is, if you need that detailed data. 
You are logging every single request. Instead, you could log the sum of requests per day/hour/whatever.

So the structure would be more like:

```
page_id | request_day | request_count
1         2015-06-14    24267
2         2015-06-14    103887
2         2015-06-13    112241
```

You save some rows that way.